# Getting ModelAndView data in angular js controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am trying to get the model data in angular js ,but not able to get it . I printed the value on spring mvc side .The data is getting stored and is retrieved successfully with the given key.Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this .

My controller-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home.web", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {
            "application/json" })

    public  ModelAndView getUSCity(@RequestParam ("statechoice") String statechoice) {


        List<String> msa = new ArrayList<String>();     
        msa = msaService.getMsaCodes(statechoice);


        /*ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Home");
        model.addObject("cities",msa);
    System.out.println(model.getModel().get("cities"));*/

        //return msa;
        return new ModelAndView("Home", "cities",msa);
    }
```

My angular js -

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.getPersonData = function() {         
            $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : 'home.web'
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(data);
                $scope.cities = data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("error");
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });

        }; 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your code into controller and service because you should not do api calls from cotroller directly(best case). Services should be used. Controllers are only be used to controlling model to show it in the view.

**myService.js**

```
app.service('myService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    return {
             getPersons: function(obj) {  
                    var deferred = $q.defer();       
                    $http({
                        method : obj.method,
                        url : obj.url
                    }).then(function(response) {
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    }, function(error) {
                        alert(error);
                        deferred.reject(error);
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                    });
                    return deferred.promise();

                }; 
         }
    });
```

**myController.js**

```
function MyController('MyController', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){
        $scope.persons = [];
        var obj = {method: 'GET', url: 'home.web'};
        myService.getPersons(obj).then(function(response){
          $scope.persons = response.data // or $scope.persons = response check yourself
        }, function(error){
           alert(error);  
        })
    }]);
```